# Multiple Post Thumbnails Plugin - Need help with code

Tags: plugins, post-thumbnails, templates, customization

I am having problems getting this plugin to run but have had little success getting it to work, even after reading past entries. I would be grateful if you could see if the code is right.

Code in functions.php:

```
'// Add secondary thumbnail (featured image) in posts */
if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) { 
new MultiPostThumbnails(array ( 
        'label' => 'Secondary Image', 
        'id' => 'secondary-image', 
        'post_type' => 'post' )
);
new MultiPostThumbnails(array(
        'label' => 'Tertiary Image',
        'id' => 'tertiary-image', )
 );
new MultiPostThumbnails(array(
        'label' => 'Quaternary Image',
        'id' => 'quaternary-image', )
);
}
add_image_size('post-secondary-image-thumbnail', 176, 58, true);
add_image_size('post-tertiary-image-thumbnail', 176, 58, true);
add_image_size('post-quaternary-image-thumbnail', 176, 58, true);'
```

Code in the relevant template (I have posted the whole template code as I think you will need to see it in full):

```
<?php

/*
    Template Name: Home
*/

?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id='main-content'>

        <h2>What We Do</h2>

        <ul id="we-do">

    <?php query_posts("posts_per_page=1&post_type=page&page_id=168"); 
             the_post (); ?>
        <!--If you want to refer to the child of parent page, use "post_parent=" -->
        <li>
            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
             <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
             <?php if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')
    && MultiPostThumbnails::has_post_thumbnail('post', 'secondary-image')) :
    MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail('post', 'secondary-image'); endif; ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="button">View More</a>
        </li>

    <?php query_posts("posts_per_page=1&post_type=page&page_id=236"); the_post(); ?>

        <li>
            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            <?php if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')
   && MultiPostThumbnails::has_post_thumbnail('post', 'tertiary-image')) :
    MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail('post', 'tertiary-image'); endif; ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="button">View More</a>
       </li>

  <?php query_posts("posts_per_page=1&post_type=page&page_id=240"); the_post(); ?>

        <li>    

            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
             <?php if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')
    && MultiPostThumbnails::has_post_thumbnail('post', 'quaternary-image')) :
    MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail('post', 'quaternary-image'); endif; ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="button">View More</a>
      </li>
         </ul>

</div><!--END main-content-->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I also want apply a class to the images but not sure where to place the array.

It might be important to note that I am also running the Featured Image functionality which is also registered in the functions template.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete example using the code you provided:

For your functions.php file:

```
<?php
// Add secondary thumbnail (featured image) in posts */
if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) { 
 new MultiPostThumbnails(array ( 
   'label' => 'Secondary Image', 
   'id' => 'secondary-image', 
   'post_type' => 'post' )
   );
  new MultiPostThumbnails(array(
   'label' => 'Quaternary Image',
   'id' => 'quaternary-image', )
   );
  new MultiPostThumbnails(array(
   'label' => 'Tertiary Image',
   'id' => 'tertiary-image', )
   );
 }
add_image_size('post-secondary-image-thumbnail', 176, 58, true);
add_image_size('post-tertiary-image-thumbnail', 176, 58, true);
add_image_size('post-quaternary-image-thumbnail', 176, 58, true);
?>
```

And for your page template:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Home
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id='main-content'>
<h2>What We Do</h2>
  <ul id="we-do">
    <?php 
      query_posts("posts_per_page=1&post_type=page&page_id=168");
      the_post (); ?>
    <!--If you want to refer to the child of parent page, use "post_parent=" -->
    <li>
      <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
      <?php 
        MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail('post', 'secondary-image', NULL,  'post-secondary-image-thumbnail');
      ?>
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="button">View More</a>
    </li>
    <?php 
      query_posts("posts_per_page=1&post_type=page&page_id=236"); 
      the_post(); 
      ?>
      <li>
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
        <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
      <?php 
        MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail('post', 'quaternary-image', NULL,  'post-quaternary-image-thumbnail');
        ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="button">View More</a>
      </li>
    <?php query_posts("posts_per_page=1&post_type=page&page_id=240"); the_post(); ?>
    <li>
    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    <?php 
      MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail('post', 'tertiary-image', NULL,  'post-tertiary-image-thumbnail');
      ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="button">View More</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div><!--END main-content-->
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: I simply copied and pasted the code above but I am finding there is not a option on the WP back-end to select a secondary, tertiary or quaternary image when i select upload image. It only gives the options for a "Featured Image" a the specified dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

For your code to work you need to change your code to this in the functions.php file:

```
<?php
// Add secondary thumbnail (featured image) in posts */
if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) { 
 new MultiPostThumbnails(array ( 
   'label' => 'Secondary Image', 
   'id' => 'secondary-image', 
   'post_type' => 'post' )
   );
  new MultiPostThumbnails(array(
   'label' => 'Quaternary Image',
   'id' => 'quaternary-image', )
   );
  new MultiPostThumbnails(array(
   'label' => 'Tertiary Image',
   'id' => 'tertiary-image', )
   );
 }
add_image_size('post-secondary-image-thumbnail', 176, 58, true);
add_image_size('post-tertiary-image-thumbnail', 176, 58, true);
add_image_size('post-quaternary-image-thumbnail', 176, 58, true);
?>
```

**Then to use the code in the template you would use this:**

```
<?php 
  MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail('post', 'secondary-image', NULL,  'post-secondary-image-thumbnail');
  ?>
```

The thumbnail will automatically add the class of :

```
.attachment-post-secondary-image-thumbnail
```

This will change for each additional size you register. It will have the class of the image size name you specify in the functions.php file.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, many thanks for answering. I am still a bit unclear how this would be applied in the template. Would I just need to repeat the code three times for the three images as I have done above or would they be grouped together?

Comment: You would just repeat the code, but change the, secondary-image to Quaternary to show that one and post-quaternary for the third. You could wrap them in a class if you are wanting to bunch them together, like this: <div class="multi-thumbs"><?php //your thumbnail code here...?></div>

Comment: I am really sorry but I am still having problems getting it to work. Would you mind looking at my template code to see if there is any mistakes?  [http://pastebin.com/0Eg76GG3]

Comment: I have edited the functions code above to reflect your code. I also want to add a class of .middle (padding settings) to each image but unsure where to apply the code.

Comment: can't you use the current class that's output by the thumbs?

Comment: In case you aren't using Firebug or WebDeveloper plugin to see the class that's assigned, here they are: .attachment-post-tertiary-image-thumbnail
.attachment-post-quaternary-image-thumbnail
.attachment-post-secondary-image-thumbnail

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me. I have applied the classes you suggested. The issue appears to be that the WP back-end is not giving me the option to select multiple images when uploading (ie., either secondary, tertiary or quaternary). It does show the set dimensions I established for a single image.

Comment: It seems to get it to work for posts and pages you'll need to add this to the bottom of the array in your functions file: 'post_type' => $type ). Then use this for a page template: MultiPostThumbnails:the_post_thumbnail('page', 'tertiary-image', NULL,  'post-tertiary-image-thumbnail');